# Enforce uniqueness on column based on contents from another column

Tags: sql-server

I have the typical Invoice/InvoiceItems master/detail tables (the ones every book and tutorial out there uses as examples). I also have a "Proforma" table which holds data similar to invoices that are sometimes linked to invoices. Both are linked to each item in the invoice, with a column optionally referencing a proforma, something like this:

```
id | id_invoice | id_proforma | amount ....... and a bunch of irrelevant stuff
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | null        | 100
2  | 1          | null        | 40
3  | 2          | 3           | 1000
4  | 3          | 4           | 473
5  | 3          | 4           | 139
```

Basically, each *item* in an invoice can be linked to a proforma. There is also a business rule that says that each proforma can be used in only one invoice (it's OK to use it in many items within the same invoice).

Currently that rule is enforced on the application side but this has problems with concurrency, as 2 users could take the same proforma at the same time and the system would let it pass. My intention is to have the DB validate this in addition to some front-end visual clues, but so far I've failed to come with an approach for this particular case.

Filtered unique indexes could serve well, except that the same proforma can be used twice if it's for the same invoice, so my question is, how can I make the DB server enforce that rule?

Database engine can be SQL 2012 or latter and any edition from express to enterprise.

Comment: is a trigger to0 heavy on insert? . Or better yet a stored procedure that checks before insert and returns 0 or 1

Comment: also you can make a unique key on two columns but you would have a problem allowing null

Comment: I would obtain a fresh `proforma_id` when the front end starts a new invoice, then mark it as "in use" in the dB using a unique identifier (by front end user/machine).  Then on saving the invoice, check the `proforma_id` belongs to the same front end instance, else get a new one.  If it winds up not being used, release it.

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik A stored procedure would can validate and lock as needed, but then I would need to redirect every DB access though it and consider insert and updates, in addition to skipping most of the application DAL (using ORM, not like it's easy to bypass it reliably). As for the triggers, it's not my first option, having problems with snapshot isolation, but if nothing else comes I would certainly consider them. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The unique key would not work, as there can be repeated values (my sample includes them) when the same proforma is in two items in the *same* invoice. What I would like to avoid is the same proforma in two *different* invoices. A filtered index could easily overcome the problems with `null`.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Could you elaborate on this technique? From what I've understand, it relies mostly on the "good will" of the client, and might be subject to race conditions without proper locks. Also if something bad happens (client crashes for instance) it might not be released ending up with an non-applicable proforma. It doesn't sounds very tempting, at least at first sight, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No you got it, its very client dependant.  You could run clean up jobs in SQL to release unused ID's after X hours or such.  Triggers as suggested might work better, but it depends on how you'd want to handle conflicts.

Comment: You could do this with a check constraint.

Comment: @TabAlleman No, a check constraint only verifies data within a single row, not taking into account other rows. I don't see how they can help here.

Comment: @Alejandro  A check constraint can be used to call a UDF that checks the other rows in the table and returns a true or false if it finds matching rows.

Comment: @TabAlleman UDFs in check constrainst, while possible, are best avoided for a variety of reasons. See those links: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/078b720f-faac-425c-b51a-33bcecb263d2/check-constraint-with-udf-problem-with-lots-of-data?forum=transactsql, http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx. I would chose a trigger instead, and deal with those problems.

Comment: @Alejandro Well, I am willing to agree that one should be aware of the pitfalls in using UDFs in check constraints.   Saying that they're "best avoided" is too blanket-y for me to agree with.   There can also be cases where they are the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user-defined scalar function that returns TRUE if the proforma id and invoice id combination are valid. Then put a check constraint on the table requiring the function to return true. Like this (tweak to fit your table name/needs):

```
-- Here's the function:
create function dbo.svfIsCombinationValid (
                                           @id_invoice  int
                                         , @id_proforma int
                                          )
returns bit
as
begin;

   declare @return bit = 1;

   if exists (
              select 1
                from dbo.YourInvoiceProformaXRefTable
               where id_proforma = @id_proforma
                 and id_invoice <> @id_invoice
             )
   begin;
      set @return = 0;
   end;

   return @return;

end;
```

After that, you can alter the table and add the check constraint:

```
alter table dbo.YourInvoiceProformaXRefTable
add constraint CK_YourInvoiceProformaXRefTable_UniqueInvoiceProforma
check (dbo.svfIsCombinationValid(id_invoice,id_proforma)=1);
```

This is OK with nulls (multiple id_invoice can have id_proforma NULL values). but if both values are not null, then the combination must either be NEW or the same as existing rows.